# Move block during his appearance

Tags: javascript, jquery

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/4BnG3/) can be seen that the first block appears and then changes it's margin.

How can I make it so that these two events occurred simultaneously?

I'm tried to run this two functions simultaneously, but it did not work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#box1').fadeIn(2000); 
  $('#box1').animate({marginLeft: '100px'});  

}); // end ready
```

Comment: `fadeIn` animates the opacity. So, do that instead with your `.animate` function call?

Comment: @Felix Kling yes, it would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Felix Kling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling) said, to make these animations happen at the same time, you should animate these boxes with `opacity` using the jQuery method `.animate()`. That way, you're making this all one animation instead of one animation and then another.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Hide these boxes not with display:none, but with opacity:0 and then change their opacity to 1.
    $('#box1').animate({marginLeft: '100px', opacity: '1'}, 2000);  
    $('#box2').animate({marginLeft: '100px', opacity: '1'}, 2000);  
}); // end ready
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4BnG3/1/

Comment: If you need to support IE8 and below, you can add `filter: alpha(opacity=0);` with your `opacity: 0`. so your rectangle won't appear immediately as the page loads in IE8 and below.

jQuery will handle the animation with alpha correctly without any intervention from you.

Comment: @Noble Mushtak I did not think that it will be solved so easily, I probably reworked, tnx.